# etcd go clientv3 Txn.If.Then.Else executes both Then and Else

Tags: go, transactions, etcd

Go 1.21 and etcd 3.5.9.

I have a go code that establishes communication with etcd db:

```
func main() {

    endpoints := []string{"localhost:2379"}

    certFile := "client.pem"
    keyFile := "client.key"
    caFile := "ca.pem"

    cert, _ := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certFile, keyFile)

    caCert, _ := os.ReadFile(caFile)

    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

    config := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
        RootCAs:      caCertPool,
    }

    client, _ := clientv3.New(clientv3.Config{
        Endpoints:   endpoints,
        DialTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
        TLS:         config,
    })

    defer client.Close()
    ...
}
```

Then I try to perform a transaction against etcd db:

```
    ...
    cc, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
    r, e := client.KV.Txn(cc).If(clientv3.Compare(clientv3.Value("hello"), "=", "world")).Then(op(0)).Else(op(1)).Commit()
    fmt.Println(r, e)
}

func op(i int) clientv3.Op {
    fmt.Printf("Custom logic executed within block %d\n", i)
    g := fmt.Sprintf("hello%d", i)
    return clientv3.OpGet(g)
}
```

My problem is that I got output to console:

```
Custom logic executed within block 0
Custom logic executed within block 1
```

But I only expect to see `Custom logic executed within block 0`, since I do have a key `hello` with a value `world` inside an etcd db. What am I doing wrong?